# Drupal 7 Fields used for Variables

Tags: php, variables, drupal-7, field

I need to use the fields in a content page to act as variables in a script running on the same page.  I doing this so the client can just update the field rather then search through the script which would be a disaster. How would I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the node ID for the piece of content you're interested in, then use `node_load($nid)` to get the node object. All of the fields will be represented there, though you may have to examine the object to figure out exactly what the data structure is.

You could just `var_dump()` the node object to the page as a simple, cheap way to figure out the name of the property you want and which indices, if any, to specify in your script. (once you figure it out, it won't change.)

Comment: It displays on the content page where I placed the code in a php filtered page.

Comment: I just need to be able to extract a field and display it wherever I want.

Comment: Then get the node ID of the relevant node, and use node_load to get information about that node. You may also need to do this in a custom module rather than in a filtered PHP field; I don't know what it filters out.